Remove Horizontal CFL from Recessed Lighting
My kitchen has recessed compact fluorescent lights that are mounted parallel to the floor, not pointing down.  When trying to replace the two in one setting, the glass separated from the bases, and now I can't remove the bases.  I have tried wriggling them and using pliers to pull them out but could not, I think primarily because the horizontal alignment makes it hard to use much force.  I am stuck, what do I try now?
The photos show more.




Spray the base(s) with non-conducting penetrating lube, let soak overnight, then use an offset screwdriver (or other appropriate prying device) to pry the bulb-base away from the socket.
When re-installing new bulb, use dielectric grease on the contact prongs and base prior to insertion.
Consider updating fixture(s) to modern LED style because compact flourescent bulbs will be going the way of the buggy whip...

While I agree with you about updating the fixtures, if the OP is only intending to replace the bulbs at this time, it may be easier to simply remove the fixture—or at least the metal can—to gain better access to yank the bulb bases.

Thanks for the specific tips.  @Huesman, the metal can is removed in photos 2 and 3, I can't remove anything more unless I cut into drywall.

@ZacharyST the screws are still in the can in pic #2 tho.

@Huesmann oh I see, thank you for pointing that out.  I had removed some cylindrical metal thing that was held in with prongs, I thought that's what you meant.
